# MFC Ribbon Control and AFX_WM_ON_CHANGE_RIBBON_CATEGORY

Tags: winapi, mfc

A have a window with Ribbon control. Ribbon control has three categories in it... I have handler for AFX_WM_ON_CHANGE_RIBBON_CATEGORY message:

```
LPARAM CMainFrame::OnRibbonCategoryChanged(WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp)
{
    CMFCRibbonCategory *pCategory=m_wndRibbonBar.GetActiveCategory();
    int nCategory=m_wndRibbonBar.GetCategoryIndex(pCategory);

    return 0;
}
```

When I start this application on my Windows7 machine my categories have indices: 1, 2, 3, but if i start the same application on Windows Server 2008, then indices will be 0, 1, 2...

Is it a BUG? How to make it work on different platforms?

Comment: Just an idea: On Windows 2008 you have usualy not enabled visual themes. You usally have only the Windows classic theme enabled. May be thgat makes a difference. Switch the Windows 7 to the classic theme and check again. Anyhow

Answer (score 1):

I Suggest you to use category name instead of its index.

Example:

```
LPARAM CMainFrame::OnRibbonCategoryChanged(WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp)
{
    CMFCRibbonCategory *pCategory=m_wndRibbonBar.GetActiveCategory();

    CString strCatName(pCategory->GetName());

    if (strCatName.CompareNoCase(_T("Home")) == 0)
    {
        // Do something
    }
    else if (strCatName.CompareNoCase(_T("My Category")) == 0)
    {
        // Do something
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Hope it can help.